# How to practice mindfulness

Tags: personal-practice, meditation-mindfulness

How to practice mindfulness during the day?

I have been know known to be absent minded and forgetful but perhaps it's due to my Karma. The problem is so bad that is someone else makes the mistake due to their mindlessness I am automatically blamed without knowing the facts!!!!!

I have been told that meditation clears out ones' Karma and that mindfulness during the day is another form of meditation (I already sit on the floor Burmese pose 30 min twice daily and breathe in, breathe out)

How to gradually start being mindful? It seems rather overwhelming .... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by adding Walking Meditation to your practice.

Next, when you finish your meditation and are about to go on with your day, make a resolve to be mindful and try to keep that mindfulness as you leave the meditation.

Then start setting aside key times during the day when you will accomplish some activity mindfully.  For instance, it could be meal-time, or a break in which you take a walk or do your exercise.

Gradually expand that mindfulness practice to include other parts of your day.

You could also carry a mindfulness timer or app that will chime at regular intervals to remind you to be mindful.

Most important: don't get discouraged.  Getting distracted or falling back into old patterns is natural.  Mindlessness is a habit, and like all habits, it takes work and there is backsliding.

Comment: I'm looking at Karma from a Bhagavad Gita perspective that actions from past life puts us in situation we are now, but we can overcome Karma with the right thoughts and actions. When I said the mindlessness is from Karma, I was acknowledging that something can be done about it.

Comment: I'll definitely start with walking mindfulness, especially when commuting to and from work ...

Comment: @Glowie got it.  Answer edited to remove that last sentence about blaming Karma :)

Answer (score 2):

> How to practice mindfulness during the day?

When you are doing your daily activities be mindful off any sensation you get through objects that come to your come in contact with. If you are holding a broom be mindful of the touch sensation. When you are standing scan your body to see what posture you are in.

> I have been know known to be absent minded and forgetful but perhaps it's due to my Karma. The problem is so bad that is someone else makes the mistake due to their mindlessness I am automatically blamed without knowing the facts!!!!!

This happens to everyone. When you realise this. Look at the sensations what the distractions has caused. Lets say you were day dreaming then what kind of sensations this cause.

> I have been told that meditation clears out ones' Karma and that mindfulness during the day is another form of meditation (I already sit on the floor Burmese pose 30 min twice daily and breathe in, breathe out)

Meditation clears out your Karma. Past Karma (fabrication) create sensation now. What ever the sensation be equanimous without craving or aversion.

> How to gradually start being mindful?

This takes practice. Follow what has been said before.

Answer (score 0):

> How to gradually start being mindful?

Well that's it isn't it?

The answer is in the question.  The beauty of the nonsense we tell ourselves is that as we become aware of it, it ceases to have power over us.

For example:  I suspect that somewhere in the background you are harboring some notion that something will happen when you become sufficiently mindful - enlightement, happiness, perhaps something more subtle.  I suspect also that you think (I'm not picking on you - I promise this isn't personal to you) something like 'being mindful is a place you get to, and then you know you are mindful....maybe other people will notice too and treat you accordingly - and once you are there that's kind of it - that's now who you are and things work out nicely after that.'

Bad news - It isn't like that at all.

Good news - It isn't like that at all.

It's good news because there's nowhere to get.  Thus, you can't fail.  You can't succeed either, but you can master the game (mastery is not an endpoint).

Thus the most self-aware / mindful thing to notice is when you are not being mindful.

"Huh.  I was just lost in my mind for like fifteen minutes."  As soon as you notice, you have the opportunity to return your attention to the present, regaining awareness.

You go to 'sleep' 2 seconds later - start thinking about your favorite movie - no problem!  Notice that you went away - don't make it wrong or scold yourself - just notice - and then come back; ad infinitum.

As I said; mindfulness is not the end - it's not even the goal - I sometimes allow myself to flow along with my thoughts for long periods at a time - I like my thoughts.  However, mindfulness allows for certain side effects.

The side effects of awareness include but are not limited to:

1. Increased effectiveness
2. Less time spent upset
3. Hearing what other people are saying instead of what you say to yourself about what they are saying
4. Increased capacity for ... anything.
5. Less time spent indulging in self-pity.

In any moment, your access to awareness is recognizing that you are not aware.

To listen to people better - notice how you don't listen.

To meditate more effectively, notice what it is that pulls you from the present.

To be more compassionate - notice where you're being a jerk.

You have everything you need to work with wherever you are standing, because the only things there are to work with are what you bring with you.

By becoming aware of what is already there, you allow for the disappearance of what is there.  When what was in the way is no longer in the way, you can move freely.

Mindfulness is not the 'mindfulness'.

'Mindfulness' is a word.

Mindfulness is emptiness.
Mindfulness is like a master gardner preparing soil for growth.

'Mindfulness' is like trying to plant in rocky, weed infested sand.

Comment: Interesting that I'm reading this answer at this moment. When I struggle with negative thoughts it takes me a while to pull myself out of that "ditch" and change my thoughts, If I'm suddenly attacked with negative thoughts I try to quickly bring focus to what is happening and use my mind to "change the channel". I guess that's what mindfulness is ...

Comment: That's part of it for sure.  I think there are three things you can do with negative thoughts:  Resist them; Submit to them; Or 'be' with them.  When you resist them - push them away rigidly - they might go away, but they'll still be there and will come back stronger.  When you submit to them, you accept them as the truth and they become real, dominating you.  When you 'be' with the thoughts, you notice them; and let them be.  When you let them be, they let you be.  Thoughts are meaningless and weightless;  it is our resistance to thoughts that gives them form and shape.  We give them meaning.